# (Sublime text vs Eclipse) Compilation Error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, sublimetext

When I implement Linked List in Sublime Text, there is an compilation error: "cannot find symbol." But in Eclipse, it works well. I can't understand why there is an error when compiling in Sublime Text.

Here is my code.

```
package list.linkedlist.implementation;

public class LinkedList
{
    ...
}

-------------------------------------------------------

package list.linkedlist.implementation;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList numbers = new LinkedList();

    }

}
```

Sublime Text shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQCX1.png)

Comment: You need to put `LinkedList` onto the classpath when compiling `Main`. Eclipse automatically does that for you  so I assume Sublime Text doesn't.

Comment: They are already in the same package. How can I put **LinkedList** class into the **Main** class? Is there any way to put it into the **Main**?

Comment: You don't put `LinkedList` _into_ `Main` but you put it on the classpath when _compiling_ `Main`. When using `javac` you'd use the `-cp` or `-classpath` option, though I can't tell you how to configure that in Sublime - you'd have to look that up in the docs.